# Codility Objective-C testing for Missing-Interger runtime error?

Tags: objective-c

Question:

```
Write a function:
int solution(NSMutableArray *A);
that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A of N integers, returns the minimal positive integer that does not occur in A.
For example, given:
  A[0] = 1    
  A[1] = 3    
  A[2] = 6
  A[3] = 4    
  A[4] = 1    
  A[5] = 2
the function should return 5.
```

My code in Xcode:

```
-(int)solution:(NSMutableArray *)A {

    int N = A.count;

    NSMutableArray* flag = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:N];
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        flag[i] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        int value = [A[i]intValue];
        if ( value <= N && value >= 1) {
            flag[value-1] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
        } else {
            // should not happen
        }
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( [flag[i]intValue] == 0 )
            return i+1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

It works. But in Codility, it shows the following error message:

> Your test case [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2,5,7] : RUNTIME ERROR (tested program
>   terminated unexpectedly) Output: : Uncaught exception
>   NSRangeException, reason: Index 0 is out of range 0 (in
>   'replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:')

Does anybody know the reason? Thanks

Comment: The comment that `else { // should not happen }` is not technically correct, since for example, the input array could be { 1, 500, 6 } with the answer being 2.  However, your algorithm still works since the answer will always be a number between 1 and N.

Comment: That's right. I should do some error handling there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `arrayWithCapacity` is just a hint to the framework code.  It says that you expect to add that many elements to the array, but it **does not** actually create an array with that many elements.

The array is initially empty and you aren't allowed to use subscript notation to add elements to the array.  So this line

```
flag[i] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
```

should be

```
[flag addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
```